# Understanding how to use nnet in R

Tags: r, nnet

This is my first attempt using a machine learning paradigm in R. I'm using a planet data set (url: https://www.kaggle.com/mrisdal/open-exoplanet-catalogue) and I simply want to predict a planet's size based on the size of its Sun. This is the code I currently have, using nnet():

```
library(nnet)
#Organize data:
cols_to_keep = c(1,4,21)
full_data <- na.omit(read.csv('Planet_Data.csv')[, cols_to_keep])

#Split data:
train_data <- full_data[sample(nrow(full_data), round(nrow(full_data)/2)),]
rownames(train_data) <- 1:nrow(train_data)
test_data <- full_data[!rownames(full_data) %in% rownames(data1),]
rownames(test_data) <- 1:nrow(test_data)

#nnet
nnet_attempt <- nnet(RadiusJpt~HostStarRadiusSlrRad, data=train_data, size=0, linout=TRUE, skip=TRUE, maxNWts=10000, trace=FALSE, maxit=1000, decay=.001)

nnet_newdata <- predict(nnet_attempt, newdata=test_data)
nnet_newdata
```

When I print nnet_newdata I get a value for each row in my data, but I don't really understand what these values mean. Is this a proper way to use the nnet() package to predict a simple regression?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When `predict` is called for an object with class `nnet` you will get, by default, the raw output from the nnet model applied to your new dataset. If, instead, yours is a classification problem, you can use `type = "class"`.

See [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nnet/html/predict.nnet.html).